# leiningen run a AOT compiled java class

Tags: clojure, leiningen

### Context

If I want Lein 1.7 to start out with a particular class loaded, I do:

```
:repl-init init.init
```

Now, instead of having lein load up a *.clj file, I want lein to do the equiv of  "java Foo", where Foo is classes/Foo.class

### Question:

My project.clj look alike:

```
(defproject ...
  :aot [Foo]
  ???? )
```

What do I put in ???? to make "lein repl" startup by executing "java Foo" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can still use :repl-init for this by having a call to the class you want pre-loaded in a namespace that gets loaded by the repl. in this example i'm using `println` statement as a standin for the setup you want done :-)

project.clj:

```
(defproject foooo "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :aot [foooo.core]
  :main foooo.core
  :repl-init foooo.core)
```

core.clj

```
(ns foooo.core
  (:gen-class))
(println "setting up for fun")

(defn -main [])
```

compiling: 
    arthur@a:~/foooo$ lein compile
    Compiling foooo.core
    Compilation succeeded.

running:

```
arthur@a:~/foooo$ CLASSPATH=./lib/clojure-1.3.0.jar:./classes/ java foooo.core 1
setting up for fun
```

or:

```
arthur@a:~/foooo$ lein run
setting up for fun
```

REPLing:

```
arthur@a:~/foooo$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 63392
setting up for fun
foooo.core=>
```

Comment: The problem: I mis-disagonised the problem. I was running JavaFx in my :gen-class's main, and apparently, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104193/does-javafx-support-starting-your-own-thread , JavaFX must be the main thread -- which explains why nothing popped up.